# UIImagepickercontroller- video is more than 10 min Issues-IOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

If the video is less than 10 min it works fine ,if the video is  more than 10 min it shows the tempFilePath empty.
Here is the code:-

```
NSString *mediaType = [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerMediaType];
NSURL *selectedVideoUrl;

if (CFStringCompare ((__bridge CFStringRef) mediaType, kUTTypeMovie, 0) == kCFCompareEqualTo) {

    tempFilePath = [[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] path];
    selectedVideoUrl = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
}

NSLog(@"tempFilePath %@",tempFilePath);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help: from the [UIImagePickerController Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html):

> Movie capture has a default duration limit of 10 minutes but can be
>   adjusted using the [videoMaximumDuration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImagePickerController/videoMaximumDuration) property.

Comment: UIImagePicker.videoMaximumDuration=600.0f